# i cant import telegram even though i installed pytelegrambot

Tags: python, visual-studio, telegram

I'm new to vscode and im trying to create a telegram bot using python.

I installed the package using cmd `python -m pip install pyTelegramBotAPI`

[image]

I've searched online but none seem to fix my problem.

If its something to do with my environment and stuff,I used Venv and used this environment
[image]

Comment: Did you install using the command line?  Are you sure that is the same installation of Python?  From your command line, if you do `python -V`, does it also say 3.9.4?

Comment: @TimRoberts it says 3.9.7

Comment: The you have two different Python installations on your computer.  You either need to use VSCode to install your package, or you need to configure VSCode to use your system-wide installation.

Comment: oh okay. I changed the environment to 3.9.7 and it works now. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @TimRoberts. I had to my environment was on the wrong version so I had to change it to the correct one